# What are the etiquette regarding recitation of Tehillim order for the sick?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, tehilim-psalms, choleh-sick

Let me be more specific about **my question's topic**:  in regards to praying Tehillim for individuals I am referring, here, to the recitation of Psalm 119 (the personal portion following the standard order of prescribed Davidic Psalms preceding it). *****

**Question itself**: What should I have done for the name מִרְיָם seeing as it ends in a ם and that is not an available corresponding letter in Psalm 119? The way I dealt with it was to just repeat the verses for מ at the end of her name.

*****At the shul where I usually attend, we do not say Tehillim during services, but recite/sing a short prayer for complete healing in the middle of Friday night services. So, the Tehillim order is fairly new to me, except for my brief exposure to it at a Chabad shul. Thanks. And may Hashem merit us all to have a full and speedy recovery from these winter illnesses!

Comment: Thanks for the editing suggestion. It's hard to find a balance between adding too much and too little on here! (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, people do as you did: use the verses for the corresponding medial letter where there's a final letter in a name. I've seen this done for the very name you ask about, מִרְיָם, actually (among others).